# Getting a deduped npm tree

Tags: node.js, npm

When installing Node (e.g. `v10.4.0`), it comes with a copy of npm that is deduped and avoids extremely deep paths. e.g. looking under `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmhook\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch`, there are no sub-folders because the child modules have been moved closer to the root.

However, when downloading the official zip from https://github.com/npm/npm/archive/v6.1.0.zip, you end up with something that is *not* deduped, and has very long paths. e.g. taking the same example as above, it goes much deeper than `npm-registry-fetch`:

```
node_modules\libnpmhook\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\node_modules\es6-promisify\node_modules\es6-promise\lib\es6-promise\promise\resolve.js
```

Likewise, if running `npm install npm@6.1.0` in a clean folder, you end up with the same deep tree.

**Question**: how can one obtain or produce an npm tree that is optimized, and similar to the one that gets installed with Node itself?

Comment: @RaphaMex do you mean that if you try running `npm install npm@6.1.0` in a clean folder, you don't get those folders at all? That seems odd.

Comment: You're right, I was on npm 5.6.0. Have you tried [npm-dedupe](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe)?

Comment: Running `npm dedupe` on that folder appears to be a no-op. In fact, I thought `npm install` was doing that by default. Would be interesting to find out how the Node guys produce the npm that gets installed with Node.